# In Rails HTML forms How To Get Value in one form and displaying in the same form even refreshed after Post method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails i am using html form to get values from the user and saving the values in session[:value],after clicking submit i can get this values return back in different view pages ,but i can't get this values in same page where i posted , when i refresh the page the session values gets destroyed

```
 def new 
session[:value0] = params[:name]
session[:value1] = params[:email]
session[:value2] = params[:phone]
session[:value3] = params[:city]
session[:value4] = params[:country]
if session[:value0].present?
redirect_to user_step1_path
end
```

end

```
Routes
get 'user/new' , :to => "user#new"
post 'user/new' , :to => "user#new"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you refresh your page, you match this route :

```
get 'user/new' , :to => "user#new"
```

But you have the same logic of the "post" method but there is no data sended, so all values are set to nil.

So, with your logic, you just have to do that :

```
 def new 
  session[:value0] = params[:name]     if params[:name].present?
  session[:value1] = params[:email]    if params[:email].present?
  session[:value2] = params[:phone]    if params[:phone].present?
  session[:value3] = params[:city]     if params[:city].present?
  session[:value4] = params[:country]  if params[:country].present?

  if session[:value0].present?
    redirect_to user_step1_path
  end
end
```

I think it should works for you !